# How to display all custom fields associated with a post?

Tags: custom-field

What is the best way to display/dump **all** custom fields associated with a post? It doesn't have to be pretty, I just need to verify what is being saved in what field array for debugging.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use [get_post_custom()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) which returns a multidimensional array with all custom fields of a particular post or page:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_post_custom($post_id));
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I'm using this function to print the array, how can I specify only two custom fields to print their key and value? custom1, and custom2

Comment: @Anagio take a look at this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Answer (score 2):

get_post_custom($post->ID) is what you need