# Retrieving custom post type fields without a post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have reviewed [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/18318/25110), however I don't think that's good enough for what I want to do.

I'm developing a plugin that needs to be aware of different fields available on custom post types, so I want to be able to retrieve that list for a given type.  I don't want to have to hard code in a specific Post ID, because what if the type exists yet there are no posts available? Is this even a realistic concern?

What the answer to that question advocates is to get a post of the custom post type first, then get the custom fields with:

```
get_post_custom($post_id)
```

Is it not possible to just query wpdb somehow in order to generate this list, rather than find a post and *then* call `get_post_custom`?  I am retrieving the list of post types via `get_post_types()`

**Update**

What I'm using this for is integrating a search service provider, and I want to let an Admin user decide which specific fields of each post type to include in the search index. If a new post type is added with custom fields and before any new posts of this type have been added the admin visits my settings page, I believe there will be issues. Besides, conceptually, I don't feel I should *have* to reference a specific post in order to get information about it's type (it could be that Wordpress itself disagrees, however).

Comment: if you have no posts, then there can't be any post meta fields.

Comment: Sounds like an incredibly specific use case.  You may receive some helpful input if you can briefly describe your challenge.  There are likely alternative approaches to be suggested.