# How to get all custom fields of any post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta

I have several post types. I want to get all custom fields associated with that post type.

Example:

```
Post
-- image
-- Featured image
-- body
```

I need to get all fields or custom fields in array. I found a solution [from here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18318/how-to-display-all-custom-fields-associated-with-a-post-type), but it does not serve my purpose:

```
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(get_post_custom($post_id));
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I need all fields with a post type. it may be feature image or body, custom field. Not for post. :)

ex: array( 'post_type'=>array('image,body,title,featured_image'))
post type may be page or post or anything. 

i hope clear now.

Comment: Have you a piece of code, again? A piece to show us. Here is nobody to write a code for you.

Comment: i am not coding any thing. i need idea. i am not telling any body to code for me. I search lots of time to find the solutions. Now i am searching in wordpress core how to they retrieve field with other custom fields in a post or page. If i found i will answer it here.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code to find mistakes in. Otherways I'll delete your post as the fail to meet the requirements of this site.

Comment: Ok You can. you are not able to understand what I want... :)

Comment: You should clear your question. I think you want registered custom fields and others default field for a custom post type. If that, it is possible. If you use acf or pods, or types i can give you solutions. Because they keep log in the database and you can easily get value from database using query. The solution is complex and if you not know the structure of wordpress, you can not achieve this solution.

Comment: @user115277 let me know if I interpreted your question correctly with my answer, and I will edit your question to clear up the confusion

Comment: thanks, @bosco both solutions help me a lot. I actually needed all custom field associated with a post type using advanced custom field (acf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code in the functions.php

**for acf**

```
function get_all_meta($type){
              global $wpdb;
              $result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
                  "SELECT post_id,meta_key,meta_value FROM wp_posts,wp_postmeta WHERE post_type = %s
                    AND wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id", $type
              ), ARRAY_A);
               return $result;
          }

function acf(){
    $options = array();
    $acf = get_all_meta('acf');
    foreach($acf as $key => $value){
      $options['post_type'][$value['post_id']]['post_id'] = $value['post_id'];
      $test = substr($value['meta_key'], 0, 6);
      if($test === 'field_'){
        $post_types = maybe_unserialize( $value['meta_value'] );
        $options['post_type'][$value['post_id']]['key'][] = $post_types['key'];
        $options['post_type'][$value['post_id']]['key'][] = $post_types['name'];
        $options['post_type'][$value['post_id']]['key'][] = $post_types['type'];
      }
      if($value['meta_key'] == 'rule'){
        $post_types = maybe_unserialize( $value['meta_value'] );

        $options['post_type'][$value['post_id']]['post_types'] = $post_types['value'];
      }
    }
    return $options;
  }
```

This will give you the array value of post meta key for acf.

**How to use**

```
foreach(acf() as $key => $value){
update_post_meta(76, $value['type'], 'Steve');
}
```

**For pods**

function pods(){
        global $wpdb;
        //get the pods post types id.

```
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
      "SELECT ID,post_title,post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = %s", $type
    ), ARRAY_A);

// pods each field for a post type create separate post type so again query to get the field post type result.
    $pods_field_post_type = array();    
    foreach($result as $value){
    $pods_field_post_type = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT ID,post_title,post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = %s
    AND post_parent = %d
    ", '_pods_field',$value["ID"]
    ), ARRAY_A);

    }
$fields = array();
   foreach($pods_field_post_type as key => $value):
     $podsAPI = new PodsAPI();
     $pod = $podsAPI->load_pod( array( 'name' => '
  post' ));
     $fields[] = $pod['fields'][$value['post_name']]['type'];
  endforeach;
  }
print_r($fields);
```

**How to use**

```
foreach($fields as $key => $value){
update_post_meta(76, $value, 'Steve');
}
```

function acf() and pods() give you the exact meta key of that post type.
If you copy and paste the code it may not work.

Hope this answer help you and also others.

let me know you not trouble anything.

Answer (score 6):

### Post Type Features

Several options exist to obtain a list of ["features"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#supports) which a particular post type supports. The easiest is to simply use [the `get_all_post_type_supports()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_all_post_type_supports/):

```
$post_type_features = get_all_post_type_supports( 'post' );

print_r( $post_type_features );
/* Array
 * (
 *   [0] => author
 *   [1] => editor
 *   [2] => thumbnail
 *   [3] => excerpt
 *   [4] => trackbacks
 *   [5] => custom-fields
 *   [6] => comments
 *   [7] => revisions
 *   [8] => post-formats
 *   [9] => title
 * )
 */
```

You can also use [`post_type_supports()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_type_supports) to see if a post type supports specific features.

Another way to check a post type's features it to obtain it's post type object and simply check the `$supports` property:

```
$post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'post' );

print_r( $post_type_object->supports );
```

---

### Custom Fields

Since [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) are [post meta-data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API) associated on a post-by-post basis rather than a post-type, there is no direct way to retrieve a list of custom field names used by a particular post type.

Rather, you would have to compile an array yourself by looping through every post of the post type in question and using `get_metadata( $post_id )` or `get_post_custom_keys( $post_id )` to retrieve every custom field stored for that post. This is potentially a ***very*** expensive operation and should be done as infrequently as possible - if this is something you are considering doing more than once every week or month, I'd highly recommend that you look into other means to accomplish your end-goal.

A custom SQL query to determine this information is also possible, and would no doubt be significantly more performant than querying meta-data for every post of a post type.